# Add a trailing slash mod_rewrite

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, centos

just wondering how I add a trailing slash at the end of my URLs using Mod_Rewrite?

This is my .htaccess file currently:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?pageName=$1
```

My URL show like so:

wwww.**********.com/pageName

I want it to show like so:

wwww.**********.com/pageName/

The URL is holding a GET request internally, but I want it to look like a genuine directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily add a trailing slash to the URL that a client sees, but you'll have to take into account that trailing slash in requests that you get after you've redirected the browser.

So the redirect could look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

And you'll want it above the:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?pageName=$1
```

ruleset, because the redirect needs to happen before the routing to `index.php`. Note that when the browser gets redirected to a URL that ends with a `/`, your `index.php` rule will have the **pageName** param with a trailing slash in it.

Comment: Yeh, that worked, but the problem now is exactly as you said, the GET is now including the slash in the actual value :/ any ideas how to make it simply superficial?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it's still useful for others that find it.

Jon Lin's answer is correct, I would add this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

The OPs comment about removing the trailing slash, since you know it will always have a slash at the end, you could `$pageName = substr($pageName, 0, -1);`. That's what I'm doing at least.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: I said that I wanted to add the trailing slash, and not remove them. Also, this would only work if the slash was included in the database record. The way that I'm doing requires you to use mod_rewrite using apache, nothing to do with PHP mate, cause we're rewriting the way that the URL displays get requests.