# My mod_rewrite rules aren't rewriting as expected

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pretty-urls

Couldn't find an answer for this on S.O. (Sorry if duplicate)

#### [localhost]/MySites/.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) compiler.php?id=$1
```

Request for `//localhost/MySites/Example.com/` works on my browser.

Request for `//localhost/MySites/Example.com` (no trailing slash '`/`') redirects (address bar actually changes) to `//localhost/MySites/Example.com/?id=Example.com` with a trailing `/?id=Example.com`.

Why is it doing that? Defeats the purpose of "pretty URLs".

Comment: Is `Example.com` a directory?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, yes it is... but then the PHP just pulls [sitename]/pages/home.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
DirectorySlash Off 
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /MySites/ 

# add a trailing slash for directories 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) compiler.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Oh I see, is it first redirecting slashless URLs to slash first, then running my rules?

Comment: Well poop.. just copy/pasted all that and both slash and no-slash go to a 404.

Comment: Tell me exactly what URL is causing 404? Also is there any other rule other than shown in my answer?

Comment: Anything on `//localhost/MySites/...` goes to a 404. (Again, `.htaccess` is in `/MySites/` directory and no other .htaccess files on the whole site.) This is with ONLY your rules (just copied/pasted the whole thing)... but playing around with it, it seems to be lines 6-9 that are the problem

Comment: Oh, scratch that... looks like the `RewriteBase /` was screwing it up... Now it seems to work... oh, and I just see you updated to /MySites/... works now... thanks, bro!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57876/discussion-between-philtune-and-anubhava).

Comment: Nice work, @anubhava +1 Since philtune said it works I wonder why it's not accepted yet.

Comment: Thanks @zx81. philtune: Do you still have any problem with this solution?

Comment: Morning. Yes, the redirect never did seem to work. The ?id=... had gone away, though. So I guess that technically answered my question. Still trying to figure out how to redirect my slashless URL to a slashed one. Thanks again @anubhava.

Comment: @anubhava, can I suggest an update? The accepted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723308/add-a-trailing-slash-mod-rewrite showed a better redirect script (that actually makes sense to me): `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]` <-since my sitenames are actual directories, I removed the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` condition.